# Problem with keeping in memory Blazor .NET MAUI Android App

Tags: c#, android, .net, blazor, maui

I've created app in Blazor.NET MAUI on Android. I hadn't created a local database, so app keeps all data in memory.

My problem is app always restarts after longer time not using. It doesn't crush and doesn't turn off - app is still running, but after a some time context's starting from beginning.

What's a problem? I use app on Samsung.

My first idea was problem is in dependency injection, because everything was set on scooped - not singleton. But it hasn't helped.

Comment: My guess is you have made a mistake somewhere. Learning [how to debug](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) will help you find it.

Comment: I can't understand what problem with keeping data in cache/memory has common with debugging code. I have written problem appears after longer time - not in actually moment...

Comment: If you manage to get android process running forever, you will be the first one.